# Credit report - Not able to establish identity

Tags: united-states, credit-report

I have tried following things with no success:

1. Request credit report online at www.annualcreditreport.com (3 times with 2 months gap)
2. Request credit report via mail ( 2 times with 6 months gap)

Every time, I was told to provide additional documents for my identity.
I have tried with my Passport photocopy, Driver's license photocopy. But they just do not seem to accept it/ find my records.

The reply from Experian says:

> We need more information to honor your request. The Social Security
>   number you gave us does not match the identification information in
>   our database.
>
> Please send us: documentation from the Social Security
>   Administration(Form SSA-L996 or any other valid SSA form that
>   indicates your name and Social Security number)

I am not sure why my credit report is not being found, as I can see it on my Credit Karma account. 
This is the first time I am requesting my credit report and I have less than one year of history.

Comment: Did the institution request further documentation? What exactly are their responses to you?

Comment: Not accepting it, and not finding any records, are two different things. If they didn't accept it they should have told you why not and how to fix that. If they didn't find any records, I would expect that they'd be as interested in understanding why not and fixing it as you are.

Of course, the key may be that with "less than one year of history", there's actually nothing official there yet and Kredit Carma is interpolating/guessing/making something up.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but for some strange reason I have misplaced the reply I got. I will post the details ASAP.

Comment: I have added the reply from Experian.

Comment: So... did you send them your form from the SSA?

Comment: I sent them the SS card photocopy. I got no response. I had to request again and this is the second time I got this letter.

Comment: So contact the SSA, request that form, get the form, and submit the form to Experian. Apparently something got messed up in your records -- which may indicate a data entry error or may indicate theft-of-identity. You need to work with them to fix it. They can't request the SSA form; you can. Do so.

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but since just got bumped today... What's the question; is it "How can I establish my identity with Experian?" ? Also, as an aside, "The Social Security number you gave us does not match the identification information in our database." is a red flag to me that someone may be using the OP's SSN illegally. All the more reason to be checking the credit report.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from their response, they would like you to send a copy of your social security card. Your drivers license or passport will not help verify your social security number. Another option you could try is to get your credit report from one of the other credit bureaus. You should be able to choose from Experian, Trans Union, and Equifax all on annualcreditreport.gov

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you begin by double checking what kinds of credit products you have and to which credit bureaus your bank reports. Not all financial institutions report to all bureaus. For example, if your bank only reports your one and only line of credit to Experian, TransUnion still won't have a file on you. Also, some lines of credit such as being an authorized user on a credit card aren't tracked by all of the bureaus.

The other thing to consider is the amount of time that your lines of credit have been open. You said it's been less than one year but if it's been less than six months you might try waiting six months to try requesting your reports.

If none of the above solves your problem, I would respond to their letter exactly as they instruct you to. Send everything certified with return receipt, and get into the habit of saving all of these records. When you send your reply be sure to include all of the requested information, a brief summary of your issue, and a reference to their previous letter to you. If they don't respond to your letter or they aren't able to help you, try calling the credit bureaus directly to inquire about the problem. Usually the consumer phone lines are automated, so try the corporate or business contacts they list on their website.

On a final note, never submit your information on any of the bureaus websites. By doing so you agree to binding arbitration agreements which limit your right to sue. Only communicate with the bureaus by mail or on rare occasions phone.

Answer (score -2):

The suggestion may be very delayed, have you personally gone to the Experian Office with all the documentation (in xerox copy and in original)? If not, please do so, there is always a difference between dealing with govt/semi-govt institutions over electronic channels and in person.